# How to connect a PNP inductive proximity sensor to a PC?

Tags: proximity-sensor, pnp, pc

I have a PNP metal proximity sensor. I am using it to test a door lock mechanism.

I need a way to connect this sensor to a PC and make a user interface to show me the signals and the values. I haven't got any experience  with any electric stuff before so can you help me with the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Read the datasheet?

Comment: 1-) what is the model/name of the sensor? 2-)you wrote "connect this sensor to pc" do you mean sending sensor output voltage as data to PC through a microcontroller and a USB protocol/cable? 3) if yes which microcontroller which protocol? 4-) will you write your own program to interpret the data in PC side?(you might need to adjust baudrates and other stuff to receive the data correct)

Comment: Would you like driving lessons too? or is there some way we can advise you to read before you write using datasheet links, plan, purpose, tolerances, skill-set. there are certain prerequisites for learning and asking EE questions.  Maybe DIY site is better suited or go shopping 1st.  "LMGTFY" https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&biw=1333&bih=1019&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Z9fIWsGdGqeCjwSXzb3YCg&q=PNP+metal+proximity+sensor+software&oq=PNP+metal+proximity+sensor+software&gs_l=psy-ab.3...18122.19568.0.19854.9.9.0.0.0.0.154.824.7j2.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.hfX_ppbsSsA

Comment: 1-model is : OMCH HLJ18A3-8-Z/BY 300mA
2-yes
3-i have no idea 
4-i don't mind if the language is easy to use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Next time when you ask a question, well, **anywhere**, please enter more detail about your problem, like what the part number is of the stuff you're trying to make it work.

[image]

I'm going to assume your sensor has wire outputs like the above. Since you're new to electronics, I suggest you get yourself an Arduino and follow the basic tutorials to familiarize yourself with how to do stuff with electronics.

Basically, one of the basic things you can do with an Arduino is to get data that's on the Arduino to your PC through something called "serial". Use that. For making a UI wrapper around Arduino, I suggest you use a programming language you're most familiar with, and a UI framework like Qt or something like that to build yourself a UI. Basically every programming language has support for reading serial data.

As for the microcontroller part, try reading this question: [Interfacing an inductive proximity sensor with a Microcontroller using a sort of PNP-NPN transistors combination](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192425/interfacing-an-inductive-proximity-sensor-with-a-microcontroller-using-a-sort-of)

Comment: 1-okay thanks for that advise i will take it in consedration
2-yes it has a configuration like that it has 3 wires

Comment: 1-okay thanks for that advise i will take it in consideration.
2-yes it has a config. like that it has 3 wires.
3-its model is : OMCH HLJ18A3-8-Z/BY 300mA.
4-i am able to run it very well on Arduino but the test of the durability of the lock runs at a different cycles (sometimes the cycle will be 500k or 750k).
so if the user wants to change that cycle he needs to open the Arduino software to change that.
5-that's why i want a UI to be able to change it and A (module) to connect it with the PC i just need where to look and i will start myself  thanks again for ur help